# jquery tableExport Export negative values has the quote at the beginning

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-table, tableexportjs

When I export to excel or xls a table with negative values on some fields, those fields start on the exported file with a quote.

In this cases I would have expected to have just the value with the minus and not the quote.

Load data on a table where values are negative and positive
Export the table on CSV or Excel
Open the exported file (negative values have a quote)

How can I export the data keeping negative values as numerical (without the quote)?

I have tried using:

```
jQuery('.MyTable').bootstrapTable({
          exportOptions: {
            fileName: 'custom_file_name',
            preventInjection: false
          }
        });
```

I saw from this link https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/4032 that `preventInjection: false` will solve the issue but i am unable to resolve still.

Thanks

Comment: It could be a version issue. Try with a different versions to check if it is a version issue.

Answer (score 2):

Fix is the way `preventInjection: false` is done is wrong.

Following code works fine:

```
jQuery('.myTable').tableExport({
            preventInjection: false,
        });
```

I hope it helps someone.

Thanks